# I want to invoke ant for multi-module build

Tags: ant

My Project structure is like below

```
|-- build.xml  
|-- module1  
|    |-- build.xml
|-- module2  
|    |-- build.xml
.
.
.
.
+-- module N
     |-- build.xml
```

There may be N number of modules each containing its own build.xml. So I want to invoke all build.xml for all modules from main build.xml.
So how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [`subant`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) and [`sequential`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html) elements. Especially the `subant` documentation contains some good hints on how to get this working.

The fact that the modules seem to be in the root directory and not contained in a separate parent directory makes it a little trickier, but it should still be doable, probably with a [`dirset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) and some wildcards to filter the directories.